# how to access or set input field in controller if input is not binded with ng-model?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have some html code which is rendering by backend.

html code :

```
<form  name="mk" ng-submit="submit()">
    First name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey">
    <br>
    Last name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse">
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

i have to get or set  `firstname` and `lastname` field. how is it possible in controller ? i don't want to use javascript or jquery.please suggest how is it possible in angular js.

Comment: `document.forms["mk"].elements["lastname"].value` - You have to use JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

A way to achieve this is, if you have the name on scope:

JS:

```
$scope.name = {};
$scope.name.firstName = "Mickey";
$scope.name.lastName = "Mouse";
```

HTML:

```
<form  name="mk" ng-submit="submit()">
    First name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" value="{{name.firstName}}">
    <br>
    Last name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="lastname" value="{{name.lastName}}">
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Example:

http://plnkr.co/edit/CsVsbYPU8hExLfGQ4NGW?p=preview

Comment: updated the plunker, http://plnkr.co/edit/CsVsbYPU8hExLfGQ4NGW?p=preview, bound correctly now, basically, you should bind to an object on scope rather than on one variable